# Not able to use findById/findOne

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mern

I am trying to fetch the data by id and have used several options but I am not getting the desired output.
Following code gives me the data of the first id in the db no matter what the id I am providing.

```
export const fetchWebpageById = async (pageId: any) => {
  try {
    let result =await webpage.findOne(pageId );
    return {
      data: result,
      success: true
    };
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(
      `at:"repositories/webpage/fetchWebpageById" => ${JSON.stringify(error)}`
    );
    return {
      success: false
    };
  }
};
```

Alternatives that I have used:
Gives result same as above

```
export const fetchWebpageById = async (_id: any) => {
  try {
    let result =await webpage.findOne(_id );
    return {
      data: result,
      success: true
    };
  }
```

`let result =await webpage.findOne({_id:pageId} );`=> gives error
`let result =await webpage.findById(_id );` => gives error

```
export const fetchWebpageById = async (pageId: any) => {
  try {
    let result =await webpage.findById({_id:pageId} );
```

=>gives error
`let result =await webpage.findById(pageId );`
=> gives error

what else can I use to get the proper data according to id ?

Comment: your pageId is a string ?

Comment: I have used type as any @AhmadMOUSSA

Comment: why any and not string | number ? If you do console.log(typeof pageId) what you get ?

Comment: I get object as type @AhmadMOUSSA

Comment: First of all do you have any error messages to post? Second, according to the Mongoose ODM API [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) expects an object as first parameter like `findOne({_id: pageId})`, but you should definitly go with [findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) to query by identifier.

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA   I am only facing this particular problem when I am trying to fetch by id, I just tried to fetch by other parameter such as url and it worked with findOne

Comment: ERROR => CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: { pageId: '62026f6d959b200db96e7580' } }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "webpages"            reason: TypeError: Argument passed in must be a Buffer or string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters - @0x1C1B

Comment: you're passing object  `{_id: { pageId: '62026f6d959b200db96e7580' } ` to `_id` you must pass string like `{ _id: '62026f6d959b200db96e7580' }`